# Issue with background-size and 100% height blocks

Tags: css, responsive-design, zurb-foundation

I'm building a vertical layout with many slides, each one has 100% height to fit on different resolutions. I'm using zurb-foundation 5 front end, and in the top part of the site I'd like to create a background slideshow with orbit; to acheive that, I organized the markup so that each one of the 'li's which form the orbit slider has 100% height and a personal background image. Evreything is working ok, the only issue is that, once the page is loaded, when I increase the height of the browser, my background doesnt become bigger.

That's the HTML markup:

```
<section id="top">
  <ul class="top-slider" data-orbit>
    <li class="slide1">
    <li class="slide2">
  </ul>
</section>
```

And the CSS one:

```
html, body, #top, #test {
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  margin:0;
}

.orbit-container, .orbit-container ul {
  height:100%;
}

.slide {
  height:100%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position:center;
  background-size: cover;     
}

.slide1 {
  @extend .slide;
  background-image: url('../images/slider_1.jpg');
}

.slide2 {
  @extend .slide;
  background-image: url('../images/slider_2.jpg');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to use "max-width" instead of "width".

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for the answer, unfortunatly it doesn't work. Anyway, I solved adding !important to

```
.orbit-container, .orbit-container ul {
  height:100% !important;
}
```

:D